# JAVA How do I generate integers between 1 and 24 but I need a pair of each integer

Tags: java

I'm making the memory game concentration.
In this I have a specified obligation to generate random pairs of numbers.
These are to be assigned to a cell at its creation on a game board. 
My problem lies not in how to generate a random number as I am able to do this with --

```
type = generator.nextInt(NUMBER_OF_ROWS*NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS);
```

However I must make sure that when I am populating my game board with Cell objects

```
board[row][column] = new Cell(this,type, row, column);
```

I have 2 cells of the same type, in order for the game to function.
Basically
I need 12 pairs of numbers that have been randomly generated.

Thanks

Varun

Comment: I don't see the issue. You have the random number, just put it in two random cells. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Need to place the same type of Cell in two different random locations in the 2D array board (or the game board whatever you want to look at it as).

Comment: You want exactly two cells of same type or there can be many cells of same type?

Comment: Generate 24 cells(12 pairs) placed randomly on board array.

Comment: What I'm saying is why don't you do `board[randomRow1][randomCol1]=new Cell(this, type, randomRow1, randomCol1);` and then repeat it for `randomRow2` and `randomCol2`, and use the same type in the Cell constructor? If you know how to generate random numbers that should be all you need to do.

Comment: So generate 2 random rows and 2 random columns. Place the same cell type in both. Then put in a check that I cant place a cell at a place where the location is NOT empty.

Comment: Until the whole game board is full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert the problem.  Rather than think of generating 24 random numbers, what you really want is to distribute the numbers 1-12 randomly into a 24-cell array, with each number going into TWO randomly selected cells in the array.  The simplest way to do this would be be to create a `List<Cell>`, populate it with 24 cells (two containing value 1, two containing value 2, etc), and then use `Collections.shuffle(List<?>...)`

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. But I think you want to have two cells of same type i.e you have 24 cells and you want to make 12 pairs of them. If you want the cells to be random you can generate two random rows number and two random column number and pair them. You have to look that the pair is not repeated.

EDIT: No function can generate pair of numbers. What you can do is number the cells in 2-D array , like suppose the row count is 3 and columns is 2 then number it like 0,1,2,3,4,5. Now start generating random numbers and set the upper limit to 5. Suppose the first no. generated is 2 and second one is 5 then you can call it a pair. Then again generate the numbers. Next pair can 1 and 0 and so on.

Comment: Basically
I need 12 pairs of numbers that have been randomly generated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not familiar with 2 Dimensional arrays or my understanding of the question is wrong. I think the game requires the player to remember a pair of cells. Totally there are 12 pairs so have a 2D array with one index varying from 0 to 11 which denotes pair number and another index which distinguishes the two cell numbers in a pair.

You need to store in an integer array called pairtype[12][2] two numbers which are paired. Say suppose cell no 1 is paired with 15 then there will be one value {1,15} in the array pairtype. So you can store 12 pairs of two integers in the array pairtype.

What mistake you are doing is using type which can range from 0 to 23 to assign to a cell type. Instead use the first index(index1) of pairtype[index1][index2] as cell type which will then vary from 0 to 11.

You also need to take care not to generate pairs like {1,15} and {1,12} in the array pairtype.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand

Comment: jim's soln is better!!! srry i don't kno much of java and what a list is and whether an array index ranges from 0-11 or 1-12